# how to groupby a dataframe if its row value is not present?

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe of countrywise open and solved complaints

```
country   complaints            status
india    network issue          solved
usa      internet speed issue   open
uk       network issue          open
india    internet speed issue   solved
usa      network issue          open
uk       voice issue            solved
```

I wanted to group by countries where status is open
i tried

```
df = df[df.status=="open"]
```

then

```
df.groupby("countries",as_index=True).count
```

the output i got is

```
country complaints
usa      2
uk       1
```

but the output want is

```
country complaints
usa      2
uk       1
india    0
```

since india has no open complaints I am unable to get  india after groupby. How take data is a way such that the groupby also brings india value as 0

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df['status'].eq('open').groupby(df['country']).sum()
```

Output:

```
country
india    0
uk       1
usa      2
Name: status, dtype: int64
```

Comment: ok thank pls tell me how can i divide this series                                                                                india    0
uk       1
usa      2                                                                                                                             
with this values                                                                                                                            0      26
1      20
2       6

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only count that country values so for that instead of using **group by** you can use **value_count()** method, it's use to count the categorical value

so your code will be look like this

```
df = df[df.status=="open"]

df.country.value_counts()
```

then your output will become like this

```
india    0
uk       1
usa      2
```